# Fluid Mechanics Infinite Plate Assumption

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

What should be the correct definition for a flow between infinite parallel plates? If I have a very long rectangular channel with height H and width W, can I approximate the flow through the channel as a flow between parallel plates? When can/can't we approximate a channel flow as a flow between infinite parallel plates? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to determine the velocities everywhere in the channel?  What are you trying to determine in terms of the forces?  Are the edges of the channel in the W direction rigid or open?

Comment: @ChetMiller Yes I am trying to determine the velocities in the channel, and the edges are rigid.

Comment: And this is for pressure flow?  If so, you need to solve a Poisson equation for the cross-section.  For a very wide channel, the velocity will only be different within a couple of channel heights from.each edge.

Comment: @ChetMiller Right that's what I would expect for a pressure flow --- solving a Poisson equation. Do you know under what circumstances can we just apply the results for pressure flow between infinite parallel plates (because those results are easier than solving a Poisson equation)?

Comment: When the height is < the width/10.